# Angular Count of Items based on date range. Last month, Current month, current week

Tags: angular, date, typescript

I have an angular component that calls a service to retrieve JSON objects back from a MongoDB. Everything works just fine here.

Within myObj I have a field, installDate, which is in Date format. I am wanting to display the length output of the JSON objects. I know how to get the total count of the objects which in in my html as

```
{{(data)?.length}}
```

How would I display a count of the amount of JSONs returned on a date range? I am looking for the length of last month, current month, and this week?

Thank you in advanced.

**My Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { myObj } from "../../myObj";
import { myService} from "../../myService";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [myService],
    templateUrl: './template.html'
})
export class Component implements OnInit {
    public data: myObj [];
    public filterQuery = "";
    public rowsOnPage = 10;
    public sortBy = "installDate";
    public sortOrder = "desc";

    public constructor(private _dataService: myService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._dataService
            .getAll()
            .subscribe((data: myObj []) => this.data = data,           
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log("getAllItems() complete"));
    }
 }
```

**My Service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { myObj} from "../../myObj";

@Injectable()
export class myService {

   constructor(private _http: Http) {
   }

   public getAll = (): Observable<myObj[]> => {
       return this._http.get("api/records")
           .map(data => data.json());
   };
}
```

**My HTML snipbit**

```
<div class="row">
    <h4 class="col-xs-6">Total Records: {{(data)?.length}}</h4>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="data | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"
               [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <mfDefaultSorter by="installDate">Install Date</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th>
            <mfDefaultSorter by="appName">App Name</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>            
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let audit of mf.data">
        <td>{{ audit.installDate  | date:"yyyy-MM-dd" }}</td>
        <td>{{ audit.appName }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Could you reiterate the question, and describe what your issue is and what you've tried to accomplish your result?  I keep thinking you're just trying to output a length of some JSON objects based upon what you've asked, but I know there is more to it than that, but don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now. But basically I am just trying to output the length of the JSON objects but based on a date range. I am trying to figure out how to get the length of items created last month, the current count for this month as well as the current count for this week.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense.  Since you're just wanting to output the length of each based upon date range, I would create a length variable for each (weekCount, monthCount, etc), then when the service yields the results, run a method which iterates through the output, then pushes the iterated object to the respective array, if the date value meets the range criteria.  Then in the view, output the variable.length.  This wouldn't really be something where you'd write a custom pipe or anything, since you're not displaying/manipulating the _result_, but rather, just the length of the result.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. When it comes to proper architecture, does it make since to write the logic to figure out the items in my date range in my Service? Then pass the output to my component? Or should it all be done in the component? I'm assuming its the service, but just want to check.

Comment: You're correct in that this probably should be done at the service layer, mainly for performance impact.  You could also look into implementing it with [oData, since I believe they support date for filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277779/1076368), then you should only need to modify the query for the result set by date range.  *edit - just realized you're using MongoDB for it.  IDK if there is something like that, [but there is a connector for the oData queries for it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-v4-mongodb).  Hope that helps.  Good luck.*

Comment: Thank you sir! This is a huge help